# immunarch splitting B and T cell datat for downstream analysis

Tags: r

What I want to do i split the analysis based on wether the clonotypes originate from B or T cells. I'm trying to determine (for example) the top 10 clones in just T or just B cells from the .txt post MIXCR analysis

```
library(readr)
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
library(pheatmap)
library(immunarch)  # Load the package into R
# To load the whole folder with every file in it type:
file_path = paste0(system.file(package="immunarch"), "/extdata/io/")
  mydata <- repLoad("D:/.R/immunarch by patient/")
data(mydata)  # Load the test dataset
repExplore(mydata$data, "lens") %>% vis()  # Visualise the length distribution of CDR3
repClonality(mydata$data, "homeo") %>% vis()  # Visualise the relative abundance of clonotypes
repOverlap(mydata$data) %>% vis("heatmap2")  # Build the heatmap of public clonotypes shared      between repertoires
geneUsage(mydata$data[[1]]) %>% vis()  # Visualise the V-gene distribution for the first repertoire
repDiversity(mydata$data) %>% vis(.by = "Sample", .meta = mydata$meta)  # Visualise the Chao1  diversity of repertoires, grouped by the patient status
top(mydata$data[[1]])
coding(mydata$data[[1]])
noncoding(mydata$data[[1]])
nrow(inframes(mydata$data[[1]]))
nrow(outofframes(mydata$data[[1]]))
top(mydata$data[[1]])
###Tracking clones top 10 clones
tc1 <- trackClonotypes(mydata$data, list(1, 10), .col = "aa+v")
###Visualizing them 
p1 <- vis(tc1)
p1
```

This is a portion of the code I'm using, at the moment all I want to do is split the data so only top T or B clonotypes are shown. Any ideas?